# How to import a maven project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a (command-line) maven based project which just works great (mvn clean, mvn verify, install all perfect)! I want now import this into eclipse **not as maven project** but regular eclipse project.

I did it but I have a dependency issue which I solved by just copying all the jars created into the .m2 folder to another folder into my eclipse workspace. Then I've added all these jars to my project.

everything ok!

Question is: I have the feeling that this is not the best way to manage the dependency in eclipse ... what do you suggest? best practices

Comment: What are you not importing it as a Maven project? This would be the normal thing to do... for a Maven project.

Comment: Please edit the title of your Question to describe the core issue of your Question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple java project which is made up of only one module, using Eclipse is very simple. To generate the Eclipse project files from your POM you execute the following command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

If you have created or checked out the project with Eclipse, you only have to refresh the project in your workspace. Otherwise you have to import the project into your Eclipse workspace (From the menu bar, select File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace). In the latter case the project (directory) should not be located in your workspace, because Eclipse might come into trouble, especially if you want to use Eclipse as the scm client.